# Is a Servlet Instance a thread or a Process?

Tags: java, servlets, process, java-threads

So I need to stop a Servlet running on the server in JavaEE 6.

I am using the command kill

```
kill -9 pid
```

So should the pid be a Servlet process id, which I can get from the following command.

```
ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()
```

But is this stoping the specific servlet thats running?

Do I need to get the pid of the Thread?

Comment: It's neither, and you can't "kill a servlet" like that.

Comment: So is there no way that I can stop a servlet?

Comment: When a request is handled by a servlet, a thread (in a threadpool) will be executing the servlet code. Killing threads in the threadpool doesn't sound like a good idea. Why are you trying to use `kill` at all?

Comment: I am using Java to start and run some scripts on the Server. I need to add a functionality where I can stop the scripts if it takes too long to run.

Comment: @Kayaman Can you suggest any way of doing this?

Comment: @AbhishekGangadhar Are you talking about Servlets Container? It's like a server, so you can stop it. Just Servlet is simply a Java class. The container is responsible for creating the instance of that class and is responsible for this instance lifecycle, so there is nothing to stop in this case.

Comment: It depends on how and what you're running. You should edit your question to include the details of what you're doing, there's probably a lot better way to achieve it than resorting to OS signals.

Comment: So the entire idea to use JavaEE to run scripts on the server to perform some tasks. I am using Ajax calls to make requests to the server. The scripts are stored in the server itself. I am only using Java to start the scripts. So I came up with a way to use ps -ef command to search for the linux process id and use kill command to stop it. But some specfic commands don't have a script involved. ex: I need to jar some files together. In that case i can't use ps -ef cause There isn't a script file with a name to search for.

Comment: You should edit the question and include the details there, not as a comment.

Comment: A Servlet is neither a thread nor a process nor a script. You don't stop servlets with `kill -9`, or anything else for that matter unless it is a dire emergency. You don't need JavaEE to run a servlet. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP Isn't the servlet-spec a part of JavaEE?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Java / Servlets work.

Servlets are loaded into the main JVM, or Java Virtual Machine, which itself only has a single PID.

The framework you are using either needs to implement a method of reloading the servlet, or you will need to restart the whole JVM.